# Ubuntu Studio for 22.04 - Refresh in Carla does not work

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-studio

I have the issue in Ubuntu Studio that in Carla 2.4.2 the refresh for the plugin does not work...
There is an solution out.
https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=24514

It would be great if someone from the Studio team could do the change in the Carla UStudio pack.
That would be great as I dont want to destroy bindings.

Thanks all.
Markus

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site. You appear to be reporting a bug or feature request.

Answer (score 2):

[This Ubuntu Studio page](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/) mentions a problem with Carla in Ubuntu 22.04

> Carla has a Python 3.10 incompatiblity where it cannot find plugins in directories located in the user’s home directory. This was fixed upstream by the developer of Carla but was too late for inclusion in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. We are working on getting this in a Stable Release Update.

More information can be found in [this bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/carla/+bug/1969798)

See also:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274299
- [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/falkTX/Carla/issues/1590) where one might address the developer of CARLA, Mr. falkTX