# Does Ubuntu Studio require or recommend its own packages for node, react, python core or libraries?

Tags: python, nodejs, ubuntu-studio, visual-studio-code, blender

I use **Blender** weekly and **Darktable**, **OBS**, **Krita** enough to consider **Ubuntu Studio** as the heart of a new workstation I'm building. `VSCode` with one or more node, react, python Workspaces are running 100% of the time. I run several java apps, but code very little in it.

Would I give up ease-of-use/updates going with UStudio full-time as my dev *and* video production rig?

U22.04 w GNOME 42.5 is my current daily driver. I like KDE Plasma and understand I'll have dozens of WM config tweaks to make should I switch. Are there any larger concerns w Ubuntu Studio for node, react, python development?

Very few results researching [ubuntu-studio] node | react | python here:

- [This question re a python conflict](https://askubuntu.com/q/1424709/941887) was a matter of a specific package and file locations rather than python itself
- This [question has work arounds re conflicts with older nvidia cards](https://askubuntu.com/q/1396160/941887) - also relevant to me but not a blocker.

Comment: All Ubuntu *flavors* use the same repositories, thus are built from the same packages, just using different *seed* files (eg. https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntustudio.lunar/desktop) that cause different packages to be included on our ISOs. All base packages are identical regardless of flavor (*they need to be with flavor sync meetings held every second month to help ensure this!*)

Comment: This question seems a bit broad, seeking information about updates, python, Nvidia cards, and seeking opinions about usability. AskUbuntu works best if you ask a single, clear, answerable question. I see 2 specific questions and 5-8 implied questions. Advice: Try it. It's free.

Comment: Thank you, user535733. My single clear question is in the Title. **guiverc** answered that precisely in the answer I've accepted.   

Would you recommend I include my Title also in the question body? I appreciate feedback that helps improve my next interactions here. 

I also appreciate your advice and have used Ubuntu Studio enough to want to make it my everyday OS. UStudio is free, but switching OSes is a time & productivity investment. Outreach to this community is part of my diligence as is including the relevant Q&A I found before posting a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [Ubuntu *flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) use the same repositories, thus are built from the same packages, just using different *seed* files (eg. https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntustudio.lunar/desktop) that cause different packages to be included on our ISOs.

All base packages are identical regardless of flavor (*they need to be with flavor sync meetings held regularly (eg. see [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-flavor-sync-meeting-notes-may-8-2023/35642) for the May meeting minutes) to help ensure this!*) with IRC rooms etc also existing for this purpose too.

Ubuntu Studio members are good at ensuring they're aligned with everyone else; as they share resources (Qt5 with Kubuntu, Lubuntu and themselves), `calamares` shared with Lubuntu etc.

All Ubuntu *flavors* are still a Ubuntu system, meaning problems are rarely *flavor* specific (*though that does happen, but those issues are the easiest to solve as we're all so similar and anything hitting only one flavor only has a few possible packages/configs to explore and thus find & fix issues*)

Comment: The purpose of *flavor sync* meetings goes beyond keeping us in sync, we're notified of upcoming changes (*by Ubuntu/Canonical teams & anyone else who requests it*) etc, and its a place where *flavors* can alert all other *flavors* of things we're considering & get any feedback etc prior to starting the work (*as much of our work will impact others in the Ubuntu family*) etc.   I'm not involved with Ubuntu Studio (*directly anyway*) yet I speak with some Ubuntu Studio team members more regularly than I do some team members where I am directly involved - they're a good team !

Comment: This is excellent information, guiverc, thank you. "flavors use the same repositories" and "problems are rarely flavor-specific" are great answers for going with Ubuntu Studio as my everyday setup. 

sync meetings, ongoing member alignment, and your quick & helpful response give me even more confidence. Answer accepted -- many thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: I'll add this as example of a SRU fix on `calamares`; used by both Lubuntu & Ubuntu-Studio - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calamares/+bug/1992507  (*whilst I recognize names, its heavily Lubuntu with Simon & myself, but Erich signs off on behalf of Ubuntu Studio & later Aaron completed a install test too for Ubuntu Studio; most discussions on this were on IRC in #lubuntu-devel actually*) ... ie. all [official] flavors are part of the *larger* Ubuntu family... (When *mantic* recently got the new Qt5, a Kubuntu member pops in #lubuntu-devel & alerts us etc)

Comment: Very cool - these Flavor Sync Notes and bug reports are nice deep-dives beyond the already-solid release notes. https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/

I'm full-steam ahead building a daily driver around Ubuntu Studio. Thanks again @guiverc.